# Drupal payment method getting access denied for admin

Tags: php, drupal

In our company we have a payment gateway and I am doing an integration but after doing it when I do checkout I get the below error as

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

InvalidArgumentException: Class "Drupal\commerceworldline\src\PluginForm\WorldlineCheckoutForm" does not exist. in Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ClassResolver->getInstanceFromDefinition() (line 24 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/DependencyInjection/ClassResolver.php).
Drupal\Core\Plugin\PluginFormFactory->createInstance(Object, 'offsite-payment') (Line: 103)
Drupal\commerce_payment\Plugin\Commerce\InlineForm\PaymentGatewayForm->buildInlineForm(Array, Object) (Line: 218)
Drupal\commerce_payment\Plugin\Commerce\CheckoutPane\PaymentProcess->buildPaneForm(Array, Object, Array) (Line: 559)
Drupal\commerce_checkout\Plugin\Commerce\CheckoutFlow\CheckoutFlowWithPanesBase->buildForm(Array, Object, 'payment')
call_user_func_array(Array, Array) (Line: 521)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->retrieveForm('commerce_checkout_flow_multistep_default', Object) (Line: 278)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->buildForm(Object, Object) (Line: 219)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->getForm(Object, 'payment') (Line: 94)
Drupal\commerce_checkout\Controller\CheckoutController->formPage(Object)
call_user_func_array(Array, Array) (Line: 123)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}() (Line: 573)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object) (Line: 124)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext(Array, Array) (Line: 97)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}() (Line: 151)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 68)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 57)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 106)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 85)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 52)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 708)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)
```

But In actual I have the WorldlineCheckoutForm class same way when I go for Payment method module I get access denied but I am logedin as admin which has all rights. I tried to check support but could not succeed. I am able to access all pages except this particular module.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following things:

1. Delete the module completely and install it on Fresh Drupal installation.
2. In your existing installation, clear the cache by using cli or page (whatever you can access) and then try to access payment page again.
   (3) Also open that page of your existing installation in Incognito mode so that it cannot get anything from cache

Hope these steps help, otherwise upload it elsewhere and share the link.